# Making a simple 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a real-time graph like this: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html

The problem is that I need data like:

```
var rawData = [
[1325347200000, 60], [1328025600000, 100], [1330531200000, 15], [1333209600000, 50]
];
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rx_bytes = [];
    var iteration = 0;

    //Options
    var options = {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0,
            tickSize: 1
        }
    };

    //Initial Plot
    $.plot("#networkStats", rx_bytes, options);

    function getStatistics() {
        iteration++;

         $.ajax({
            url: '/getStatistics',
            type: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
            success: function (statistics) {
                console.log(statistics);
                var network = statistics.networks.eth0;
                rx_bytes.push({
                    index: iteration,
                    data: network.rx_bytes
                });
                console.log(rx_bytes);

                //Plot
                $.plot("#cpuStats", [rx_bytes], options);
                //get data again
                getStatistics();
            }
        });
    }

    getStatistics();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And my array output is like this: http://prntscr.com/i3y8ve

How do I make an array like the one above?

Comment: You're creating an array of objects, not a 2D array

Comment: Please take your time and read through the answers provided. Don't just rush through them and only skim the first one.

Answer (score 3):

This should solve it:

```
          rx_bytes.push([
                iteration,
                network.rx_bytes
            ]);
```

Comment: Also `$.plot("#cpuStats", rx_bytes, options);`

Comment: ah.. now it plot infinitly on x axis. I need to delete the 1st item of the array when it has like 100 points

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doesn't work without `[rx_bytes]`. I dont know why